# Do you include the scrollbar width of browsers in your media query?

Tags: html, css

First picture: "Short Bio" text does not turn blue at 317px

Second Picture: "Short Bio" text turn blue at 333px

Therefore the scrollbar is included in the media query.

Chrome's scrollbar is 16px which was calculated from 333px - 317px= 16px

[image]

[image]

Comment: Question is bit unclear. But you don't know the size of scollbar for all browsers. Also, it should be taken care by browser itself. What problem you're facing? No content resize should be done because of scrollbars.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/GEYeP                     

Left picture: "Short Bio" text does not turn blue at 317px


Right Picture: "Short Bio" text turn blue at 333px

Therefore the scrollbar is included in the media query.

Comment: Nope, that's weird. Doesn't happen on a mac but the scrollbar on a mac is hidden unless you're using it. I do, however, usually specify `body { overflow-y: scroll; }` so that the scrollbar is always visible and the page doesn't shift when you go from a page without a scrollbar to a page with one. Using that might help your media queries be more consistent.